Why does vite.js call all the js of my project in the login page?
When the login page is first rendered, a strange thing happens in
Console > Network > JS.
In this tab, when I refresh, it calls all js of the project and increases the site load time, for example 16 seconds.
But I realized something, when I put the loading in the fallback, I noticed that the first 14 seconds do not enter the panel at all, the last two seconds, the loading is displayed and the login page comes up
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    const root = createRoot(rootElement);

    root.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
     );

    import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";


    const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { open, mode, name, duration, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.root);

    const handleCloseSnackbar = () => {
            dispatch(closeSnackbar());
    };

    return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <RoutesComponents />
                <CustomizedSnackbars
                    open={open}
                    mode={mode}
                    name={name}
                    duration={duration}
                    onClose={handleCloseSnackbar}
                />
            </ThemeProvider>
    );
    };
    
    export default App;

    import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
    import { Navigate, Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";


    const Login = lazy(() => import("../Pages/Auth/Login"));
    const RoutesComponents = () => {
      const token = !!Cookies.get("sattec-token");
      const routes = BaseRoute();
      const location = useLocation();
      function activeRoute(routeName) {
        return location.pathname === routeName ? routeName : "/admin";
      }
      return (
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div className="loadingContainer">
              <div className="loadingStyle">
                <div className="loaderApp"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <Routes>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      );
    };

    export default RoutesComponents;

vite.config.js :

I checked different modes in the vite.config.js section, but I didn't get any results
Look at the picture posted
Pay attention, this number of js should not be called when only the login page should be displayed

